# How can I integrate MJML in react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mjml

I have a client-side rendered react project and I need to provide a template builder for the user where they can configure their emails. They should be able to see the preview and then hit send, the mail gets sent.

I do not see the documentation for client-side integration of MJML. Can someone please help me with the same?

Comment: check this : https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/wonderful-emails-with-mjml-and-mdx/#introduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `mjml-react` if you are working with `reactjs`. I'm not sure about the limitations (haven't used the package).